# cannot index igraph vs with output from numpy

Tags: python, numpy, igraph

I want to index the vertices of a graph with a list generated by numpy. It generates only [], although the same list specified explicitly works as expected. Here is an example:

```py
import igraph as ig
import numpy as np

# Create a graph and give the vertices some numerical values, just 0 to start.
t = ig.Graph()
t.add_vertices(10)
t.vs['inf'] = [0]*10
print('the initial list:            ', t.vs['inf'])

# Now choose a few indices and change the values to 1.
choose = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print('the chosen indices:          ', choose)
t.vs[choose]['inf'] = 1
print('indices selected explicitly: ', t.vs['inf'])
# That works as expected.

# Create the same list using numpy.
nums = np.arange(0,10)
npchoose = list(np.where(nums < 5)[0])
print('indices selected via numpy:  ', npchoose)
t.vs[npchoose]['inf'] = 2
print('this has no effect:          ', t.vs['inf'])
# The list appears identical but it does not index the .vs

# The index is actually empty. 
print('just the chosen list, explicitly:  ', t.vs[choose]['inf'])
print('just the chosen list, by numpy:    ', t.vs[npchoose]['inf'])
```

The output is:

```py
the initial list:             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
the chosen indices:           [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
indices selected explicitly:  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
indices selected via numpy:   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
this has no effect:           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
just the chosen list, explicitly:   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
just the chosen list, by numpy:     []
```

I'm at a loss because I want to select vertices for modification based on several conditions in other arrays, where numpy.where() is the most convenient tool.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions I came up with, in case someone else has the same problem:

1. Use `npchoose = np.where(nums < 5)[0].tolist()` 
   rather than `list(np.where(nums < 5)[0])`.
2. Make better use of the igraph vertex sequencing, rather than direct indexing: `t.vs.select(lambda ve: ve.index in npchoose)['inf'] = 2`. npchoose works fine as a numpy array in the lambda.